# How to get ng model default value?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, function

i using php with angular, i want set value in ng model from php expression, and then read ng-model value from controller, but these value is null :/

```
  <input ng-model="id" ng-init="id= '<?php echo $userID ?>'">
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.id = "";  
$scope.getId = function() {
   console.log($scope.id); // ==> id value is "", but in the html is 455
}
```

Comment: What's the final source code that's being output by PHP?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/cs3dM

Comment: Is your input a text, checkbox or etc..?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a way you can get id from php backend is making ajax requests by using `http` service in angular.